# Time complexity of a fragment of a code

Tags: algorithm, big-o

What is the time complexity of this fragment of a code

```
for(int i=1;i<=N;i++)
for(int j=i+1;j<=N;j++){

  somethings O(logn) operation code
}
```

Answer (score 2):

It is `O(logN * N^2)`. Inner loop is executed `(N-1)+(N-2)+..+1 = N*(N-1)/2` times (Gauss' trick for summation).

Answer (score 0):

When i=1, j=2 to N  (i+1 to N) => `something` is executed (N-1) times

When i=2, j=3 to N  => `something` is executed (N-2) times

.................

When i=N-1, j=N to N => `something` is executed 1 time

Summing all to find how much times `something` is executed :

(N-1) + (N-2) + ... 1 = N(N-1) / 2 = O(N^2)

Now, `something` itself is O(log n), the total complexity comes :

O(N^2)*O(log N) = O(N^2 log N)

*(Assuming that n and N are same)*